# Webview white screen on some phones

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

The android app that i'm building has a webview that loads a mobile website. On most phones the webview loads perfect but on some phones with android 4.4.2 the webview loads perfect the first time but when you open the app after you paused or closed it it will just show a white screen.
Now the question is - what am i doing wrong and why is this problem only on some devices?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - but with different Android versions.

For me adding the following helped. Still investigating if I can narrow down the phones for which this is necessary.

```
webview.settings.apply {
    cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
    setAppCacheEnabled(false)
}
```

It's Kotlin obviously.

Answer (score -1):

Enable the `WebView` cache by using the following properties:

```
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/com.your.package.appname/cache"‌​);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: tested and still same problem